# How do I add an associative array to an array of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an array called $hours, this array contains 24 other arrays each for the our of the day starting with 00

- $hours

  - [00]
  - [01]
  - [02]
  - [03]

How would I add a key value pair to the hours arrays so that my end result looks lik:

- $hours

  - [00]

    - key => value
    - key => value
  - [01]
  - [02]
  - [03]

Comment: `$hours['00']=array('blahblah blah');`

Answer (score 2):

You should try to [use native PHP date datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

But if you really need to learn this,

To add a value in $hours at the index "00"

```
$hours['00']['key'] => $value
```

Where 'Key' is the key of your second node level array.
By what you said I think you need a 3rd node level array.

So

```
$hours['00']['key'] => array('value 1','value 2');
```